# Expanding logarithms in the negative domain

Tags: output-formatting, series-expansion

I am trying to expand some functions $f(z,\bar{z})$ containing logarithms for $z = x + i k x$ with $x<0$, but the results are not always consistent. As a simple example, consider the following code:

```
Log[16*z*zb] /. {z -> x + 4 I*x, zb -> x - 4 I*x};
Assuming[x < 0, Series[%, {x, 0, 0}]] // Normal
Log[16*z*zb] /. {z -> x + 5 I*x, zb -> x - 5 I*x};
Assuming[x < 0, Series[%, {x, 0, 0}]] // Normal
Log[16*z*zb] /. {z -> x + 6 I*x, zb -> x - 6 I*x};
Assuming[x < 0, Series[%, {x, 0, 0}]] // Normal
Log[16*z*zb] /. {z -> x + 7 I*x, zb -> x - 7 I*x};
Assuming[x < 0, Series[%, {x, 0, 0}]] // Normal
Log[16*z*zb] /. {z -> x + 8 I*x, zb -> x - 8 I*x};
Assuming[x < 0, Series[%, {x, 0, 0}]] // Normal
Log[16*z*zb] /. {z -> x + 9 I*x, zb -> x - 9 I*x};
Assuming[x < 0, Series[%, {x, 0, 0}]] // Normal
```

The output is the following:

```
4 Log[2] + Log[17] + 2 Log[-x]
5 Log[2] + Log[13] + 2 Log[-x]
4 Log[2] + Log[37] + 2 Log[-x]
Log[800 x^2]
Log[1040 x^2]
5 Log[2] + Log[41] + 2 Log[-x]
```

Why does the expansion look different for $k=7,8$? I need those expansions to have the same form as the others. I observe the same behavior for $k=12,13$ but I cannot understand why. Any idea?

Comment: So I can expand the logarithms using `PowerExpand`, but then I have an extra imaginary piece of the form $2\pi I$. I think it is because it is not seeing the assumption $x<0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. The result for arbitrary `n` is

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[n_] = Assuming[x < 0,
  (Series[
      Log[16*z*zb] /. {z -> x + n I*x, zb -> x - n I*x},
      {x, 0, 0}] // Normal) // FullSimplify]

(* Log[16 (1 + n^2) x^2] *)
```

If you want that expanded

```
(f /@ Range[4, 13] // PowerExpand) /. x -> -x

(* {4 Log[2] + Log[17] + 2 Log[-x], 5 Log[2] + Log[13] + 2 Log[-x], 
 4 Log[2] + Log[37] + 2 Log[-x], 5 Log[2] + 2 Log[5] + 2 Log[-x], 
 4 Log[2] + Log[5] + Log[13] + 2 Log[-x], 5 Log[2] + Log[41] + 2 Log[-x], 
 4 Log[2] + Log[101] + 2 Log[-x], 5 Log[2] + Log[61] + 2 Log[-x], 
 4 Log[2] + Log[5] + Log[29] + 2 Log[-x], 
 5 Log[2] + Log[5] + Log[17] + 2 Log[-x]} *)
```

Verifying,

```
Assuming[x < 0, % == (f /@ Range[4, 13]) // FullSimplify]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear. I think you understood it perfectly though, and the output you display is exactly what I wished to achieve.

Comment: What is not clear is why you want the expanded form rather than a more compact and computationally efficient form. Presumably, there is an unstated goal.

Comment: Yes, the unstated goal is that I have large expressions of the sort, and I wish to collect all the factors of `Log[-x]` to compare them to another expression I have.

Answer (score 3):

I just found the solution. The logarithms can be expanded using `PowerExpand` with `Assumptions->x<0`. Then the expansion can be performed as usual and the result is as desired.